# Как узнать версию Google Chrome

Tags: python

Хотелось бы знать могу я как-то узнать версию Хрома средствами python

Нашел в решение

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(
    r'wmic datafile where name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" get Version /value',
    shell=True
)
print(output.decode('utf-8').strip())
```

Но данные код выдаёт ошибку

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'wmic datafile where name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" get Version /value' returned non-zero exit status 2147749911.
```

Comment: Не думаю, что так получится что-то вывести из под python'а. Но можно использовать библиотеку WMI.

Comment: @ShamusRezol, почему нет? ТС: а почему `chrome.exe --version` не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исполняемый файл `chrome.exe` имеет атрибут версии. Его можно получить, например, следующим образом.

```
import win32api

filepath = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
info = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(filepath, "\\")
ms = info['FileVersionMS']
ls = info['FileVersionLS']
version = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}".format(win32api.HIWORD(ms), win32api.LOWORD (ms), win32api.HIWORD (ls), win32api.LOWORD (ls))
print(version)
```

Или так

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

filepath = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
parser = Dispatch("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
version = parser.GetFileVersion(filepath)
print(version)
```